# Why does www.example.com resolve to a different IP than example.com?

Tags: domain-name-system

Why does `www.example.com` resolve to a different IP than `example.com` when testing with ping?

Is the fault of the server configuration (Apache)?

Comment: I'll note that `ping` is a terrible tool for troubleshooting DNS issues. You should use `dig` if you're on *nix or `nslookup` if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Most people that don't have much experience assume that www.example.com is automatically the same as example.com. The www subdomain is just that - a subdomain and will have it's own separate record in your DNS. It's common to CNAME www to example.com, but in your case, you've probably got an A record for example.com that points to your website and an A record for www that points somewhere else.

Comment: In complement, the two records mainly differ when you use the "web redirect" feature of your registrar

Answer (score 1):

Check your DNS configuration it seems that you have different entrys.